# How to create query in HQL for one to many mapping

Tags: hibernate, hql, one-to-many, jpql

I have two entity as below

```
public class Author{

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = 
      "author")
   @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   private Set<Book> books;
}

public class Book{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID_REF", nullable = false)
    private Author author;

    private String bookCategory;

    private String bookName
}
```

In this tables i would like to fetch all authors except if there is a row in Book table for author with bookCategory = 'Comic' AND bookName='SuperKid'.
If bookCategory and bookName matches i should not get the author.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT author FROM Author author
JOIN author.books book
WHERE book.bookCategory <> 'Comic' AND book.bookName <> 'SuperKid'
```